# SparQL - list cities

Tags: rdf, sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm trying to list all the cities in Denmark from [Wikipedia/dbpedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Denmark_by_population) by using SPARQL.

I've tried a lot of things and I can't get it to work. This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
    <http://dbpedia.org/resource/List_of_cities_in_Denmark_by_population> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PopulatedPlace>  ?city                  
}
```

Any suggestions or ideas? Anyone know how to find out which entities are present in a wikipedia article?

This is a school assignment, so I'm just looking for advice or guidance, not a complete solution. Here's a good site for doing the [queries](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you have will probably be limited to the cities for which dbpedia knows the population. This one might be better:

```
select ?s where { 
?s a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/CitiesAndTownsInDenmark>
}
```

It returns 318 entities.